# line-height in text area css not recognized

Tags: html, css, textarea

I added line-height into my text area css but it's still not being recognized. It is still double spacing in text area.

```
form div {
position: relative;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
@include transition(all, 0.3s, ease-in-out);
background: $white-95;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid $white-85;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: $white-40;
font: 16px/42px $font-body;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0 15px;
width: 100%;
line-height: normal;
```

Comment: Is it possible that this the default browser line height?

Comment: Not sure, I will look to see if the browser is setting a default in css

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning a pixel value to your line height to force the text area to display as you want.

```
line-height: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's frustrating that CSS can set the line-height but you can't set the number of rows in CSS, just inline.

Since the default is 2 rows, your `height = line-height * 2(rows)`.

**So the answer**: Set the old fashioned `rows` attribute to 1:
`<textarea rows="1"></textarea>`.